# How to use @Output() backdropClick property of sidenav in material2?

Tags: angular-material2

I was trying to enable and disable body scroll based on sidenav open and close , don't know how to get the event while closing the sidenav.

Please help

[Click here to see the API details of sidenav](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/api)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add in `<md-sidenav-container>`.

Example:

```
<md-sidenav-container class="example-container" (backdropClick)="check()">
</md-sidenav-container>
```

[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/NfXCLN?p=preview)